# How to connect to Amazon Keyspaces (Cassandra) using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cassandra

I am trying to connect to Cassandra hosted at amazon keyspaces, and it is required to include the SSL certificate on each connection.

I already have the driver installed and the connection is successful, however the authentication fails as I am missing the certificated.

I have tried the following wrappers but none of those includes the parameter where the SSL certificate is configured:

sonvq/laravel-cassandra
Fuitad/laravel-cassandra
cubettech/lacassa

In my config/database.php file I have the following configured, and I am guessing the certificate goes in the "options" parameter but it does not work:

```
   'cassandra' => [
        'driver' => 'cassandra',
        'host' => env('CASSANDRA_DB_HOST', ''),
        'port' => env('CASSANDRA_DB_PORT', 9142),
        'keyspace' => env('CASSANDRA_DB_DATABASE', ''),
        'username' => env('CASSANDRA_DB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('CASSANDRA_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'options'   => array(
        Cassandra::VERIFY_PEER_CERT    => '/home/user/AmazonRootCA1.pem',
       ),
     ]
```

Using "cqlsh" via command line works perfectly, as in that command it is easy to configure the certificate path, but on laravel I have not been able to find how to set that path.

Any help would be great! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was killing my head since the last two days trying to connect my laravel app to amazon keyspaces.

Finally, making some changes to cubettech/lacassa I made it work

After reading the documentation at datastax, I found the way to load the amazon PEM certificate and finally I could connect.

Would be great if the following changes are made on connection.php

```
protected function createConnection(array $config)
    {
       $ssl = Cassandra::ssl()
               ->withVerifyFlags(Cassandra::VERIFY_PEER_CERT)
               ->withTrustedCerts($config['cert_path'])
               ->build();     
        
        $cluster   = Cassandra::cluster()
        ->withContactPoints($config['host'])
        ->withPort((int) $config['port'])
        ->withCredentials($config['username'],$config['password'])
        ->withSSL($ssl)
        ->withDefaultConsistency(Cassandra::CONSISTENCY_LOCAL_QUORUM)
        ->build();

        $keyspace  = $config['keyspace'];
        $connection   = $cluster->connect($keyspace);
        return $connection;

    }
```

It is required to set the certificate path variable as well.

For some reason I found that even if the environmental variables were configured, the connection was being always made to localhost, that is why I loaded the environmental variables using the $config array.

The queries return a Cassandra/Rows Object , I have to convert them to string or reading them in loops but that is not a problem.